# variable not exported causing linker error in gcc 4.9.2

Tags: gcc, linker

symbol not exported:
I have a variable in a .cpp file that gets built into a .so file. This variable added is not found during the linking process. Both the .so and executable existed- ie just added the new variable to an existing .cpp file w/o changing any build files.

Library:
in one of the .cpp files:  add the definition of a new variable:

```
std::vector<int> g_Timeout`enter code here`
//Tried these w/o success:
///init the variable to see if it is exported
std::vector<int> g_Timeout={1} ;
//add export symbol:
EXPORT_SYMBOL(g_Timeout);
```

In .so file:

nm libTimeUtil.so | grep g_Timeout
U g_Timeout
U = undefined ?

Executable:

```
extern std::vector<int> g_Timeout;
void SetDelay(std::vector<int>& vDelay)
{
    g_Timeout.swap(vTimeout);
}
```

Linker error while linking the executable:
/apps/srini/eagle/feature/src/driver/DBLibModule.cpp:1295: undefined reference to `g_Timeout'

linker has the library added in the ldd command:
lib library: 'TimeUtil', linkage: 'shared'

Comment: Which platform is this? What does `EXPORT_SYMBOL` expand to? How is `libTimeUtil.so` compiled and linked? (On ELF, global variables are, by default, global, so this should work if the defaults are used.)

Comment: Linux (RHEL). EXPORT_SYMBOL: I dont know the details- just tried something I found googling. The .so has many exported variables/functions. The only unique thing about the variable I added is: it is defined in .so but initialized by a global function in the executable